# PHP: strtotime formatting

Tags: php, timestamp, strtotime

I am trying to put a readable time and date as part of a file name (in php). I am having all kinds of trouble with this and was hoping someone could help. I have tried several different recommendations that I have read around the internet (plus I read the manual) but I really haven't gotten anything to work right. Right now I have this:

```
$Time=strtotime("now");
$date=DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y H:i:s', '7/24/2012 14:40:30');
$date_readable=$date->$Timestamp();
```

At that point I then add $date_readable to a file name. It compiles and runs but it doesn't format the date at all. It still gives it as a timestamp. 
Any suggestions on how to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do it with simple date function for example

```
$time = strtotime("now");
$formatDate = date('F jS, Y h:i:s A', $time);
echo $formatDate;
```

this will print something like

```
July 25th, 2012 1:02:29 am
```

`DateTime` class is more powerful then using simple `date` function, as `DateTime` class offers powerful API's plus it is object oriented. however for simple date conversions i would stick to php's date function. as that could do my purpose.

for more formatting option have a look at this link http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php#refsect1-function.date-parameters

Comment: I don't know why I was having such problems. I feel like I tried a solution (if not exactly then) similar to this one.

Comment: You also don't need `strtotime("now");`. `date()` assumes the current time when its 2nd parameter is omitted.

Comment: yeah, @nickb is correct, but if you have any existing timestamp from which you want to format, then you should use it like this.

Comment: someone down voted, without an explanation. if i am wrong in something you should probably leave a comment. i am willing to improve myself.

Comment: @IbrahimAzharArmar Yes it does! Thank you very much. Because I am fairly new I can sometimes get lost in all the jargon but you explained it clearly, concisely and it was exactly what I needed. Thanks again

Comment: you are welcome, the more you work on PHP the more grip you will have over the language, happy coding :)